# WordPress: failed to delete buffer zlib output compression in "ob_end_flush()"

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an error when I upload my website to the server:

```
Notice: ob_end_flush() [ref.outcontrol]: 
failed to delete buffer zlib output compression in
/srv/disk4/simscreation/www/nameofwebsite.com/wp-includes/functions.php 
on line 3747
```

Comment: Would you please also include the code of the part that is generating the error?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit accordingly.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can try follow the step in the post
[click here look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62895843/3712534)

Answer (score 0):

I found this track [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18525) but not sure why all of a sudden my server environment started exposing this problem, apparently it's been around for some time now.

The fix was to add this to the last line in my theme's functions.php:

```
//added to fix zlib bug - see: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18525
remove_action( 'shutdown', 'wp_ob_end_flush_all', 1 );
```

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693992/notice-ob-end-flush-failed-to-send-buffer-of-zlib-output-compression-1-in