# Wordpress issue,after update

Tags: wordpress, compression, buffer, zlib, notice

After wordpress is updated automaticlly i received an error in email with this error messages

```
Error Details
=============
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 369 of the file /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/plugins/thememove-core/export/export.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Class 'ThemeMove_Export' not found in /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/plugins/thememove-core/export/export.php:369
Stack trace:
#0 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/plugins/thememove-core/thememove-core.php(50): include_once()
#1 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-settings.php(360): include_once('/home/onehostsc...')
#2 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-config.php(90): require_once('/home/onehostsc...')
#3 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/onehostsc...')
#4 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-login.php(12): require('/home/onehostsc...')
#5 {main}
  thrown
```

I deactived the plugin but the error still exist i receive this :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function header_class() in /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/themes/structure/templates/header-preset-06.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/themes/structure/header.php(36): include() #1 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-includes/template.php(722): require_once('/home/onehostsc...') #2 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-includes/template.php(671): load_template('/home/onehostsc...', true) #3 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-includes/general-template.php(41): locate_template(Array, true) #4 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/themes/structure/page.php(28): get_header() #5 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-includes/template-loader.php(98): include('/home/onehostsc...') #6 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/onehostsc...') #7 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/index.php(17): req in /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/themes/structure/templates/header-preset-06.php on line 34

There has been a critical error on your website.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0) in /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4552
```

Here is code of header-preset-06.php on line 34  and the [LINK](https://murtishi-bau.ch) of website

```
    <header <?php header_class(); ?><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> role="banner" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="site-branding">
                    <?php
                    global $thememove_custom_logo;
                    if ( $thememove_custom_logo ) {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                            <img src="<?php echo $thememove_custom_logo; ?>" alt="logo"/>
                        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your theme is working with the plugin in pair. It means that your theme needs the plugin to work properly (for instance it calls the function `header_class()` from the plugin).

You should update the plugin to avoid this error (the plugin claims WordPress 5.3.2 compatibility, see https://wordpress.org/plugins/thememove-core/).

Comment: No ill try this i deleted the thememove-core plugin and installed it but still it doesnt work..

Comment: Are you using WordPress 5.3.2?

Comment: 5.3.2, yes that is the version that im using

Comment: And the theme itself is up to date? By the way, be careful, you should not let the error displayed on the website. Maybe change the option in wp-config to turn off error logging for your production version of the website.

Comment: Yes i will change it but i was trying to see what error i have how to solve this,i still do not know...

Comment: @xSupport did you try switching to another theme just to be sure the problem is related to the plugin and the theme?

Comment: Yess still doesnt work.. please help me solve this problem.. ??

Comment: @xSupport what happens if you replace the first line of the file `header-preset-06.php` by this one: `<header role="banner" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`? (make a backup of the file first)

Answer (score 0):

First check this post out :

[Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693992/notice-ob-end-flush-failed-to-send-buffer-of-zlib-output-compression-1-in)

Looks like a plug-in is conflicting with your theme 
Try to switch your WP to twenty thirteen theme or an native Wp theme and see the impact , 
I or you can deactivate  all plugins and activate them one by one and see which plugin is causing the conflicts 
If none of that works try to install a plugin called site health 
https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-to-check-for-plugin-conflicts/

Comment: Yes i have deactived them , but still it shows me error idonk know why ? >. even if i deactive the plugin that the theme is conflict with it it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to Wordpress default theme and see if the error still occurs
If you still have the problem then try to add to you we-config.php these three lines 
  ‘’’’ define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); ‘’’

After that fire up ur site and church a file called debug.log located in your work-content folder , open this file it will tell you exactly what’s wrong in a simple human readable way 
One more thing try to update your theme while giving the theme folder the right permission to read and write 
Let us know either this solved your problem or not