# Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, flush

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59292369/10846351

I followed instructions in this answer but another warning came up!

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_ob_end_flush_all' not found or invalid function name in /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 303

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more precise when asking questions. What were you trying to accomplish when the error was thrown?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.