# Bug in WordPress debugging mode

Tags: php, wordpress

do not be tired.
I encounter the following errors, please help.

```
PHP Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in /home/username/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5212
---
PHP Deprecated: _register_controls از نگارش3.1.0 <strong>منسوخ</strong> شده است! به‌جای آن از Elementor\Controls_Stack::register_controls() استفاده نمایید. in /home/username/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5316
```

Comment: Disable zlib compression on your server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notice: ob\_end\_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693992/notice-ob-end-flush-failed-to-send-buffer-of-zlib-output-compression-1-in)

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? I don't see `Controls_Stack` class anywhere in this file ( **wp-includes/functions.php** ).

Comment: If you are using Elementor, the current version is [3.6.1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/elementor/). Your errors tell that you are using 3.1.0. So, please update both WordPress and the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Use ob_end_clean() function instead of ob_end_flush();